# node.js and socket.io with SSL

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a server with fully working wildcard SSL, but socket.io give me error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

On the client side im connecting to the socket like that:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://pricer.somedomain.com',{secure: true, port:5005});
```

Server Side:

```
var io                      = require('socket.io').listen(5005);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: does it work if you use `{secure: false, port: 5005}`?

Comment: @RolandStarke all the website is https, so i cant load un secured scripts

Comment: for testing you could disable this feature (in firefox for example with about:config then search for: "mixed_content" and set the values to false)

Comment: For those without a wildcard SSL, the socket.io connection on the client can't specify a port -- so socket.io must share the port of the express server ([how to do it for express](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44436553/1467306)).  For debugging, you can avoid using SSL by allowing mixed content in the browser ([how to do it for chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24434461/1467306)).

Answer (score 3):

Your client need to connect through https://, not http://

```
var socket = io.connect('https://pricer.somedomain.com',{secure: true, port:5005});
```

I had the same problem yesterday, check on my [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565746/secure-exchanges-using-only-socket-io-and-web-client-socket-io-js).