# Socket.io: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: express, socket.io

I am trying to set up socket.io on my web site but the server logs an error saying the port is already in use (I set it to the same as my server's). I am using Express.

If I set it to a different port, I get a 'net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED' error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably creating (either explicitly or implicitly) two separate HTTP server instances that should listen on the same port, so the second instance will throw an error because the first is already occupying the port.

Instead, you can share the same HTTP server between both Express and `socket.io`, so there will be only one HTTP server that handles both:

```
const express  = require('express');
const app      = express();
const server   = app.listen(3000); // or whatever port you want
const io       = require('socket.io')(server);
```

`app.listen(...)` returns the HTTP server instance that Express will create for you. You can re-use that instance for `socket.io` by passing it into its constructor (returned by `require('socket.io')`).

Comment: Thanks. Can socket.io listen to a different port than what the server is listening to?

Comment: Yes, you can use `require('socket.io')(3001)` for instance, so the `socket.io` server would be listening on 3001 instead of 3000. However, I don't see the upside of doing that, it's much easier to run them on the same port.